# x86, summing up and rotate ascii repersention of string to 0x40

Tags: assembly, x86

What sequence of string will resulted of 0x40? The string must be self-repeate, i.e. "12341234", first part of string equal to second part of this string. rdi stores the string

```
0x00000000004010bd <+157>:   xor    eax,eax 
0x00000000004010bf <+159>:   ror    al,1 
0x00000000004010c1 <+161>:   add    al,BYTE PTR [rdi] 
0x00000000004010c3 <+163>:   cmp    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x0 
0x00000000004010c6 <+166>:   je     0x4010cd <_start+173> 
0x00000000004010c8 <+168>:   inc    rdi 
0x00000000004010cb <+171>:   jmp    0x4010bf <_start+159> 
0x00000000004010cd <+173>:   cmp    al,0x40              
0x00000000004010cf <+175>:   sete   al 
0x00000000004010d2 <+178>:   ret
```

Comment: Note that it's only comparing al, so only the low 8 bits of the sum matters.  Of course, 2x (0x40 >> 1) would do it, and that's in the printable ASCII range.  (The low bit is 0, so rotate is the same as right shift)

Answer (score 1):

From the template that you show us and assuming that only the characters that represent decimal digits are going to be used, the number of possible solutions is limited to 10000. Then why not write a loop and try them all?

In the below code, the 4-character string starts at "0000" and ends at "9999".
Instead of using a separate loop counter, it will be the final wraparound, the one that goes back to "0000", that will signal the end of the loop.

```
More:   lea     rdi, TheString

        ; call your code that calculates AL

        test    al, al
        jz      No

Yes:    ; call code that prints the string

No:     lea     rdi, TheString+3
.a:     cmp     byte [rdi], "9"
        je      .b
        inc     byte [rdi]
        inc     byte [rdi+4]            ; The 'self-repeat' part
        jmp     More
.b:     mov     byte [rdi], "0"
        mov     byte [rdi+4], "0"       ; The 'self-repeat' part
        dec     rdi
        cmp     rdi, TheString          ; Repeat until (1)0000
        jae     .a
```

The output that I got was:

> ```
> 11021102
> 11211121
> 11401140
> 13111311
> 13301330
> 15011501
> 15201520
> 17101710
> 19001900
> 30023002
> 30213021
> 30403040
> 32113211
> 32303230
> 34013401
> 34203420
> 36103610
> 38003800
> 51115111
> 51305130
> 53015301
> 53205320
> 55105510
> 57005700
> 70117011
> 70307030
> 72017201
> 72207220
> 74107410
> 76007600
> 91019101
> 91209120
> 93109310
> 95009500
> ```

So the above code works, but we can improve it quite a bit if we

- inline the code of the calculating routine, removing the `call` and `ret`
- unroll its code (partially) so we can skip redundant instructions like that first `ror al, 1`, the `add al, [rdi]` where `rdi` is pointing at the terminating zero, and the `sete al` in the end
- use only registers instead of memory for the string
- make the loop so that it has but a single aligned branch target
- branch away from the loop on a find (minority case) so that most of the time the execution can just fall through

```
        mov     cx, "00"
        mov     bx, "00"
        mov     ax, 0200h
        ALIGN   16
Again:  add     al, ch
        ror     al, 1
        add     al, cl
        ror     al, 1
        add     al, bh
        ror     al, 1
        add     al, bl
        ror     al, 1
        dec     ah
        jnz     Again
        cmp     al, 40h
        je      OK
Cont:   mov     ax, 0200h
        inc     bl
        cmp     bl, "9"
        jbe     Again
        mov     bl, "0"
        inc     bh
        cmp     bh, "9"
        jbe     Again
        mov     bh, "0"
        inc     cl
        cmp     cl, "9"
        jbe     Again
        mov     cl, "0"
        inc     ch
        cmp     ch, "9"
        jbe     Again
        ;;mov     ch, "0"

        ...

; - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
OK:     ; code that prints the string
        jmp     Cont
; --------------------------------------
```